# Mac Desktop back to iCloud (from Dropbox)

Tags: icloud, folders, dropbox

A little while ago, Dropbox took over my Desktop, Documents and Downloads folder.
I want to have it back on iCloud. How can I do this?
Activating it on Screenshot does not work, the toggle can not be used.
[image]

Comment: Have you disabled Dropbox syncing of these folders?